# Elastic search and filter

Tags: elasticsearch

What's the problem with my query? I just want to have a query to return documents with this conditions:
language_id = 28 and publisher_id in [225, 226, 227] and finally calculates the stats. I did it this way:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "language_id": 28
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          {
            "range": {
              "re_max": {
                "gt": 100
              }
            }
          },
          "terms": {
            "publihser_id": [
              225,
              226,
              227
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
},
"aggs": {
  "stat_agg": {
    "stats": {
      "field": "re_max"
    }
  }
}
}
```

It produced an error:

```
{"error":"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[CebklbvjR2ORQkaiUEm6eQ][rep][0]: SearchParseException[[rep][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [    {\r\n      \"query\": {\r\n        \"filtered\": {\r\n          \"query\": {\r\n            \"term\": {\r\n              \"language_id\": 28\r\n            }\r\n          },\r\n          \"filter\": {\r\n            \"and\": [\r\n              {\r\n                \"range\": {\r\n                  \"re_max\": {\r\n                    \"gt\": 100\r\n                  }\r\n                }\r\n              },\r\n              \"terms\": {\r\n                \"publihser_id\": [\r\n                  225,\r\n                  226,\r\n                  227\r\n                ]\r\n              }\r\n            }\r\n          ]\r\n        }\r\n      }\r\n    },\r\n    \"aggs\": {\r\n      \"stat_agg\": {\r\n        \"stats\": {\r\n          \"field\": \"re_max\"\r\n        }\r\n      }\r\n    }\r\n    }]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[rep] Failed to parse]; nested: JsonParseException[Unexpected character (':' (code 58)): was expecting comma to separate ARRAY entries\n at [Source: [B@d78a10f; line: 18, column: 23]]; }{[CebklbvjR2ORQkaiUEm6eQ][rep][4]: SearchParseException[[rep][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [    {\r\n      \"query\": {\r\n        \"filtered\": {\r\n          \"query\": {\r\n            \"term\": {\r\n              \"language_id\": 28\r\n            }\r\n          },\r\n          \"filter\": {\r\n            \"and\": [\r\n              {\r\n                \"range\": {\r\n                  \"re_max\": {\r\n                    \"gt\": 100\r\n                  }\r\n                }\r\n              },\r\n              \"terms\": {\r\n                \"publihser_id\": [\r\n                  225,\r\n                  226,\r\n                  227\r\n                ]\r\n              }\r\n            }\r\n          ]\r\n        }\r\n      }\r\n    },\r\n    \"aggs\": {\r\n      \"stat_agg\": {\r\n        \"stats\": {\r\n          \"field\": \"re_max\"\r\n        }\r\n      }\r\n    }\r\n    }]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[rep] Failed to parse]; nested: JsonParseException[Unexpected character (':' (code 58)): was expecting comma to separate ARRAY entries\n at [Source: [B@d78a10f; line: 18, column: 23]]; }{[CebklbvjR2ORQkaiUEm6eQ][rep][3]: SearchParseException[[rep][3]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [    {\r\n      \"query\": {\r\n        \"filtered\": {\r\n          \"query\": {\r\n            \"term\": {\r\n              \"language_id\": 28\r\n            }\r\n          },\r\n          \"filter\": {\r\n            \"and\": [\r\n              {\r\n                \"range\": {\r\n                  \"re_max\": {\r\n                    \"gt\": 100\r\n                  }\r\n                }\r\n              },\r\n              \"terms\": {\r\n                \"publihser_id\": [\r\n                  225,\r\n                  226,\r\n                  227\r\n                ]\r\n              }\r\n            }\r\n          ]\r\n        }\r\n      }\r\n    },\r\n    \"aggs\": {\r\n      \"stat_agg\": {\r\n        \"stats\": {\r\n          \"field\": \"re_max\"\r\n        }\r\n      }\r\n    }\r\n    }]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[rep] Failed to parse]; nested: JsonParseException[Unexpected character (':' (code 58)): was expecting comma to
```

Comment: And what is the problem? Is not working? Giving error? etc

Comment: Error updated in question

Answer (score 0):

And it should be like this (syntax wise) - you are missing a "{":

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "language_id": 28
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          {
            "range": {
              "re_max": {
                "gt": 100
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "terms": {
              "publihser_id": [
                225,
                226,
                227
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "stat_agg": {
      "stats": {
        "field": "re_max"
      }
    }
  }
}
```